# How to save Image in WebView to load webview offline

Tags: android, webview

I have content webview from my url same :

```html
<html>
<body>

<h2>Spectacular Mountain</h2>
<p>Descreption</p>
<img src="http://tttd.vn/upload_images/images/2015/12/22/22-12/cha-tom-cu-sen.jpg">
  <p>Avatar</p>
  <img src="http://tttd.vn/upload_images/images/2016/03/18/18-3/porsche-macan-2(1).jpg">
  <p>Test webview offline</p>

</body>
</html>
```

I want save Image in webview to read webview offline.
I know that to save image in webview and replace url image with path image in sd card. how to compare and replace quickly in the event of multiple image in webview? Please help me. Thank you.